# How do I make a delay so that I can replay a sound multiple times

Tags: python, audio, time, delay

So I'm just wondering how I can go about playing two beeps that last for 1 second each, with a 1 second delay between them. It doesn't seem to work when I try to `import time` and then add a `time.sleep(1)` my two function calls

```
`play_beep()`

`time.sleep(1)`

`play_beep()`
```

---

```
#Function plays a 1 second beep
def play_beep():
    CHUNK = 1024

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(-1)

    wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                    channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                    rate=wf.getframerate(),
                    output=True)

    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

    while data != '':
        stream.write(data)
        data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()

    p.terminate()

play_beep()
```

Help would be much appreciated. Anyway of fixing this would be great!

Comment: What os are you using, windows or unix based?

Comment: I am using mac os mojave